# Should I ask a question about a notable myth that I already know the answer to?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I encountered the myth about the space pen and NASA spending million dollars on its research while the USSR just used pencils:

[image: myth]

I wanted to check if it was true, so I checked it, and apparently that both [Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/business/genius/spacepen.asp) and [Scientific American](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=fact-or-fiction-nasa-spen) addressed it and proved it false. This site however doesn't have a question on it.

Should I add a question with the answer for the sake of coverage of all the myths out there, or should I leave it alone, as the answer is available to anyone interested in other notable places?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certainly yes! Add the question, and, if you will, the answer, supported by references.

> ## Etiquette for answering your own question
>
> Just post your answer immediately after you post the question. Like you say, phrase it as a request for comments to improve your solution. Your intentions are clear --- I wouldn't think you were trying to generate reputation. Besides, it's my prerogative to reward or punish your efforts. Alternatively, you could mark your answer as a community wiki if you are feeling charitable.
>
> You can [now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz) do this automatically by ticking the “Answer your own question” checkbox when posting the question, provided you have more than 15 reputation.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17847/131112

Comment: I think you can actually answer as you post the question, although I have not tried it myself.  Is this really the case?

Comment: Yes, there's a checkbox, as I mention above.